# Events in Scala

Tags: scala, events

I have a CategoryRepository class which implements several methods such that saves a category to database.
I also have an object Product that contains a list of categories.
What I want to do is to trigger an event that the Product object will listen to, and will update the product itself with the new data of its category.

In C# I know I can use delegates but I don't know if I can do something like this in Scala.

I don't want the CategoryRepository class to know the class Product so I won't call some method in Product that will update it through CategoryRepository.

My CategoryRepository class:

```
trait CategoryRepositoryComponentImpl extends CategoryRepositoryComponent {

  val categoryRepository = new categoryRepositoryImpl

  class CategoryRepositoryImpl extends CategoryRepository {

    val dbRepository = CategoryDbRepository

    def updateAttribute(id:String, request:UpdateCategoryItem): String = { 
      val cat = dbRepository.get(id)
      cat.update(request)
      dbRepository.save(cat)
    }
  }
}
```

The product repository looks the same as this category's repository.
Now I want to add a line after `dbRepository.save(cat)` that will trigger an event that will call the updateProduct() function within ProductRepository.

Please give an implementation example.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you please share an example of how you'd do it in C#? Or in pseudo-code. Just to be clear what you're asking

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax in C# but I know you can use delegate and add an event listener using += operator to add one. I just don't know if Scala has something similar...

Comment: Don't (re-)define `Product`, it's a key built-in trait in the Scala type system (all tuples and all case classes derive from `Product`).

Comment: I don't really call it Product. It's just for the sake of the explanation to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a (not so) basic implementation for an update channel based on events.

I took care to only generalize to the bare bone, as to give a hint to future evolution and code reuse.

### Base infrastructure

We introduce an updates channel

```
//Listens for updates to A's and notifies interested listeners
class UpdateChannel[A] {

  //simplified register
  var listenMap: Map[A, Listening[A]] = Map()

  //update call
  def apply(a: A): Unit = listenMap.get(a).foreach(_.event(a))

  //update call
  def registerFor(a: value, listen: Listening[A]) = listenMap += (a, listen)

}
```

and a generic listener interested in corrisponding updates

```
//Listens to changes for type A
trait Listening[A] {

  def event(upd: A): Unit

}
```

### Application

Now we adapt the Repo Component to inject the channel

```
trait CategoryRepositoryComponentImpl extends CategoryRepositoryComponent {

  val categoryRepository = new categoryRepositoryImpl

  /************** NEW CODE HERE **************
   * define a channel to send category updates
   *******************************************/
  def updateChannel: UpdateChannel[Category]

  class CategoryRepositoryImpl extends CategoryRepository {

    val dbRepository = CategoryDbRepository

    def updateAttribute(id:String, request:UpdateCategoryItem): String = { 
      val cat = dbRepository.get(id)
      cat.update(request)
      dbRepository.save(cat)
      //send the update to the channel
      updateChannel(cat)  //***************** << AND HERE
    }
  }
}
```

We also need to enable the product to event listening

```
//product must be listening to category updates
class Product(val category: Category) extends Listening[Category] {

  def event(cat: Category) = ??? //strut your stuff here

  ...business stuff here too

}
```

Finally, here we put the ingredients together

```
//put the pieces together
def wireup() = {

  //the channel  
  val catChan: UpdateChannel[Category] = new UpdateChannel[Category]

  //the Repository component wired to the channel
  val catRep = new CategoryRepositoryComponentImpl {
    val updateChannel = catChan
  }

  //a nice cat
  val myCat: Category = ???

  //a nice prod with her nice cat
  val p: Product = new Product(myCat)

  //prod wants to know what happens to her cat
  catChan.registerFor(myCat, p)

}
```

---

### Remarks

1. we can make the `Product` independent of the whole framework by using refinement types

   ```
   val product = new Product(myCat) with Listening[Category] {
     def event(cat: Category) = ??? //strut your stuff here
   }
   ```
2. a different solution would be to avoiding all the wirings and simply register a list of update *closures* in the `RepositoryComponent`

   ```
   trait CategoryRepositoryComponentImpl extends CategoryRepositoryComponent {

     val categoryRepository = new categoryRepositoryImpl

     //public listeners, they should be encapsulated
     var categoryUpdates: Seq[Category => Unit]

     [...]

     def updateAttribute(id:String, request:UpdateCategoryItem): String = { 
       val cat = dbRepository.get(id)
       cat.update(request)
       dbRepository.save(cat)
       //send the update to the channel
       categoryUpdates.foreach(_.apply(cat))
     }
   }
   ```

   }

and the product needs only to add his own update function

```
    catRep.categoryUpdates +:= (cat) => p.event(cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more or less how it's done in C# with events and delegates.
When you define `Event` like this you'd have to use tuples (`Event[(Any,EventArgs)]` for instance) if you want to pass more than one parameter to the event listeners.

```
class Event[Arg] {

  type L = Arg => Unit

  private val listeners = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[L]

  def +=(listener: L) {
    listeners.append(listener)
  }

  def apply(arg: Arg) {
    listeners.foreach(_(arg))
  }
}

class CategoryRepository {

  val event = new Event[String]

  def fireEvent(data: String) {
    event(data)
  }
}

object Product {

  def update(data: String) {
    println(s"updating: $data")
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  val repo = new CategoryRepository()
  repo.event += Product.update
  repo.fireEvent("new data")
}
```

Comment: In your example, you use Main to instantiate CategoryRepository but in my case it happens within a trait which means the trait will pass the product's update method which means that the CategoryRepository's trait knows Product. It's also something that I don't want. Can you use events instead?

Comment: Maybe you should show how your classes are structured and how and where you would like to add event listeners. Or how you would do it with delegates.